# Euler-Digits + siunitx hiding certain units (like Ohm)

Tags: xetex, siunitx, eulervm

It's been a couple of months since I last used my TeX, so I did some updates that became availabe (using MikTeX's software - Windows 7/64bit) and as of that moment, I noticed that my `siunitx` package began to have issues when used with the `eulervm` package (when added with `euler-digits` option). A couple of weeks ago I also came across a problem (I couldn't use Palatino with XeLaTeX, for some weird reason).

So I need to solve three issues:

1. I'd REALLY want to stick with `eulervm` package, added with `euler-digits` option. I like the looks of it much better and the option allows me to add some emphasis to math values.
2. Although not necessary, I'd like to keep the "Palatino" typeface. It matches the `eulervm` style much more and it has support to small-caps with bold face, which the default typeface does not have.
3. I also need the `siunitx` package as the content of the documents I need to type demand a good unit type setting!

Here's a MWE with the default typeface (Note I use XeLaTeX). If you know how to put Palatino back on there, please tell me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm]{geometry}
%
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\begin{document}

BLABLABLA... \SI{2}{\ohm}

\end{document}
```

When I compile the MWE this is what I get:

[image]

EDIT: After updating MikTeX I solved the errors in the image, although not the issue of `siunitx`. I tried some more things and discovered the issue: The `fontspec` package was the cause of it. Once I removed it (adding the `inputenc` package), compiling it with XeLaTeX worked, PDFLaTeX also worked.

Comment: your example runs without error in an up to date texlive 2015, what do you mean by "could not use palatino" what commands did you use, and what error did you get (are you using an actual palatino font or a clone such as tex gyre pagella?

Comment: I have uploaded an image of the errors that compiling the MWE gave me.

Comment: your `expl3`  and `fontspec` packages are out of sync, update both  and you should be fine. (In general it is better to show exact errors from the log file in code section so line breaks preserved, rather than an image of a summary of the errors, but in this case an update should be all you need)

Comment: Using MikTeX's update software gives me no available updates, though.

Comment: sorry I know nothing about miktex, someone will pass by though. Whatever the system is telling you your expl3 is too old for the version of fontspec you are using

Comment: all the errors after the first are spurious, it did not understand the test for luatex (undefined control sequence) and so it failed to skip the luatex-specific code and all the other errors are xetex not understanding luatex-specific code.

Comment: Did you run the update manager as admin *and* as user? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: after updating it (the user mode had updates I didn't get) the errors went away, but the problem still exists; the `\SI{2}{\ohm}` still gives me an output without the ohm symbol.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : I found out that removing the `fontspec` package worked (both compiling with XeLaTeX and PDFLaTeX). I'm not sure that's a good solution, though.

Comment: Just FYI, with an updated (as of today) TeXLive 2015, I do _not_ see the `ohm` unit if `\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}` is included. I do get the warning `Package eulervm Warning: Unknown Operator Encoding!`, `(eulervm)                Math accents may be wrong: assuming OT1 positions.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the packages in the correct order and set up `siunitx` to use `\Omega` from Euler Math:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  math-ohm=\Omega,
  text-ohm=\ensuremath{\Omega},
}

\begin{document}

Text \SI{2}{\ohm}

Math $\SI{2}{\ohm}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So you set `siunitx` to use `\Omega` as the Ohm symbol. Why did you need to do that? I suppose that the current package is missing that setup?

Comment: @GuilhermeVargas I believe that `siunitx` recognizes being called along with `fontspec` and adjusts things for that, but you're tweaking it for using Euler and things should be fixed back.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to switch to `T1` encoding for the short time of using the Omega-symbol of `eulervm`. This could look like this:

```
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{math-ohm={\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont \Omega}}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext 
Now as we had such great text in Palatino Linotype (It's the only one I could find on my system), let us test a text version \SI{1}{\ohm}, a inline-math version $\SI{1}{\ohm}$, and the very same just set without \verb|siunitx| as $1\,\Omega$. They look the same.

Finally there is just left to say:
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]